# How do i login/logout change with ati/intel hybrid graphics?

Tags: ati, hp, intel, hybrid, dv6

I have hp pavilion dv6 6030et. I want to use my ati radeon hd 6770m driver instead of intel mesa driver.

Answer (score 1):

The new Catalyst driver (12.1) supports the 6770m in the HP's. I am a bit suss about the performance though.

Comment: Please elaborate, I don't understand how to do it :)